# Using reduce method to get the multiplication of the last elements of each subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is the array: `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]`
This is how it looks like with a regular `for` loop:

```js
let multiplication = 1;
for (let i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
  multiplication *= l[i][1];
}
```

How do I do the same thing with `reduce` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiate value at the second parameter of reduce, and with the callback function, remember to return the accumulated value

Below solution could help you

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [1, 4],
];

const res = arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc * el[1], 1);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: `acc * el[1], 1` , what does the *,1* ?

Comment: @Alex `(acc, el) => acc * el[1]` is anonymous function as 1st param, `1` is the second param

Comment: @Alex yeah it's the initial value